# Build stops when running for the first time in a day and shows Restore the connection to "iPhone 5" and run "Quiz" again

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am having a problem with my Xcode 6. Sometimes when I run in simulator the build stops after few minutes and shows:

> Restore the connection to "iPhone 5" and run "Quiz" again, or if "Quiz" is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > Quiz.

This problem usually occurs when the app is running for the first time in a day. If I run again, it works perfectly.. I don't know what that problem was :( 
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on [my post in the dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/248879?tstart=0) and in the Xcode 6.1 release notes, this is unfortunately a known issues with the iOS Simulator.

> **3) "(Domain = FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, Code = 4)", "(Domain
>   NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 3"),
>   "Domain=IDEUnitTestsOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3", "Lost
>   Connection to ...", "Debugger disconnected", or app getting SIGKILLed
>   soon after launch**
>
> Upon installation of an app, SpringBoard will
>   SIGKILL that app's process in order to force a relaunch of the app
>   with the new executable.  The problem is that there is a race
>   condition whereby SpringBoard may accidentally SIGKILL a *new* process
>   that we just launched rather than the old process.  Which of the
>   various error messages you get depends on exactly when in the launch
>   process the SIGKILL was delivered.  Normally, this shouldn't happen,
>   so the advise is to just try again (sorry =/).  If you find that this
>   happes to you all the time or more frequently than you can tollerate,
>   we are incredibly sorry.  We are aware that systems with slower disk
>   I/O will see this happen more frequently than faster systems, so if
>   you are using an NFS home directory, you may want to create a local
>   directory for your simulator data and setup a simlink to it from
>   ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator

Comment: So this is unavoidable?